# I'm having trouble using the pyodbc package to connect with Microsoft SQL Server on my Mac

Tags: sql-server, odbc, pyodbc, unixodbc, azure-data-studio

I have installed Docker Desktop to run an image which runs a container that contains the Microsoft SQL Server on my Mac, with Azure Data Studio as the GUI, as such:
[Current connection to Microsoft SQL Server on MacOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dllyZ.png)

I have been trying to use the `pyodbc.connect()` function to connect to the Microsoft SQL Server, so that I can extract data from many XML files and load it into the SQL Server. However, my code keeps failing at `pyodbc.connect()`, where it gives me the error:

> conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={/opt/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib};'
> pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

I have installed homebrew, unixODBC and ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server that was on the official Microsoft website. I tried searching many websites on what to do and all I read was that I need to be able to configure the odbc.ini file, but I am unsure exactly what I need to do to configure this file properly. Currently, my odbc.ini file is blank and my odbcinst.ini file has the following content:

[odbcinst.ini file that I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm9Rw.png)

The current code that I have specifies the exact path directory to SQL Driver 18:
[my pyodbc.connect() code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4DLb.png)

Would appreciate any help regarding this,

Comment: Odd, my files on macOS are living in `/usr/local/lib`. Rather than trying to specify a path have you tried just using the driver name? e.g.: `DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};` or `DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};`

Comment: Out of curiousity, from `zsh` in a Terminal window, what does `sudo find /*(opt|usr) -name "libmsodbc*"` output?

Comment: running sudo find /*(opt|usr) -name "libmsodbc*" gave me this output:

/opt/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib
/opt/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/msodbcsql17/17.10.5.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/msodbcsql18/18.3.2.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib

I installed both SQL Driver 17 and 18 because I tried both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={/opt/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib};' pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

If `ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server` is not installed properly, then you may get the above error. Follow the [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/th-th/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-2017) to install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (macOS). Along with that, use the code below to connect to the SQL Server using `pyodbc`:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                       '<serverName>;'
                       'DATABASE=<databaseName>;'
                       'UID=<userName>;'
                       'PWD=<password>')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM <tableName>")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

It will connect successfully, as shown below:

[image]

For more information, you can refer to [this](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/1165).

Comment: I followed the instructions in the link you provided and managed to get it to connect! I can now at least execute the python file and create a table on my SQL Server in Azure! Thanks @Bhavani!

Comment: Great! Keep up the momentum!